# Consistently define fill color for bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset as this, and my goal is to make a bar chart and fill positive value with green, negative value with red:

```
df = data.frame(exp=c("A", "B", "C"), val = c(0.3,0.2,-0.1))
df$pos = df$val > 0
ggplot(df, aes(x=exp, y=val, fill=pos)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "green"), guide=FALSE)
```

Above plot works as I expected. However, if my dataset happens to be all positive values:

```
df$val = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
df$pos = df$val > 0
```

The same plotting will plot all positive value as "red" instead of "green", which is not what I want or expect. How do I fix this? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `scale_fill_manual()` add that you need `TRUE` values as green and `FALSE` as red. If you just name color names then in case of only positive values there is only one level (`TRUE`) and the first of two colors is used (is your case it is red).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=exp, y=val, fill=pos)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("FALSE"="red", "TRUE"="green"), guide=FALSE)
```